# Can whole pablanos be frozen whole?

Tags: freezing, chili-peppers

My neighbor brought me several pablanos & I can't use them all right now. Can they be frozen whole?

Comment: I don't know if there are issues due to the difference in wall thickness, but see : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5227/67

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but ideally you should roast them first. I would peel them as well. You could leave them otherwise whole if you wish, to give you greater versatility when you defrost them. If you roast, peel, de-seed, then freeze, you could even make a passable (not great, but passable) Chile Relleno out of the not-quite defrosted pepper. Stuff and bread them while still partially frozen and they'll be easier to work with.

Here's an article on the subject from [The Kitchn](http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-roast-and-freeze-green-chiles-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-193168).